# Bower install with Artifactory

Tags: github, bower, artifactory

I’m trying to set up an operation where the only internet access to external repos is via artifactory server.  I have followed the bower information on this web page http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bower+Repositories

I can successfully do the npm installs of bower-art-resolver as described (utilizing npm remote repository for npmjs in artifactory), but then trying to do the example bower install of bootstrap it fails because bower is attempting to find git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git and I don't have an access to github.com due to firewalls.

How do I make the full bower workflow work then if having the bower registry remote repository is not suffient to make the setup work?  Is there some way that the artifactory VCS functions come into play?  How would I make bower utilize that instead of trying to reach github.com?

This firewall scenario seems like a common use case for a repository server, so I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are doing the following:

(1) Create a [remote repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bower+Repositories#BowerRepositories-RemoteRepositories) in Artifactory proxying the Bower registry. Notice that Artifactory will need to access both the Bower registry and Github.
(2) Configure Bower to use the Artifactory repository you created in the previous step as the Bower registry. This should be done in the [.bowerrc](http://bower.io/docs/config/) file, for example:

```
{
  "registry": "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/bower/bower-repo"
}
```

(3) Use *bower-art* instead of *bower* when installing packages, for example:

```
bower-art install bootstrap
```

Comment: I was missing the part mentioned in (1) of your answer.  I didn't have the VCS github item enabled, I thought only the bower check item was needed.  Reading the web page more slowly I see what I was reading past now.